# AWS Lambda function returning same values unless redeployed

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

I have a simple AWS Lambda function connected to a mysql rds. When I update a field in my apps UI it updates it in the database when viewed from the MySQL workbench but when using the Lambda function it returns the same value until I redeploy the function and then it gives me the new correct value

```
"""Search Function for Lambda""" 

from urllib.parse import unquote
import json
import pymysql

# Configuration Values
##CONFIG VALUES REMOVED


# Connection
connection = pymysql.connect(ENDPOINT, user=USERNAME,
                             passwd=PASSWORD, db=DATABASE_NAME)


def get(event, context):
    """Takes searches key from event and searches the database on that key"""
    print(context)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    search_key = unquote(event['pathParameters']['search_key'])
    cmd = ('SELECT * from LCI_Data WHERE Description Like "{}"'.format("%"+search_key+"%"))
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    result = [dict((cursor.description[i][0], value)
              for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "body": json.dumps(result),
                "headers": {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
                }
            }
    return response
```

Comment: It looks like you are using API Gateway. Do you have caching enabled in API Gateway?

Comment: I do not had already checked that, moving the connection initialization into the function solved my issues though.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense why that worked. Just because you were reusing the connection, it still should have been executing the query each time instead of returning the results from the previous query.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's related to this: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving

```
connection = pymysql.connect(ENDPOINT, user=USERNAME,
                             passwd=PASSWORD, db=DATABASE_NAME)
```

into the get() function solved my issues.

Comment: You may need to close the connection explicitly each time, now that you're creating a new connection for each and every Lambda invocation (both cold and warm).